# Generic type name injection

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm writing my angular app in typescript.
For sake of redundancy prevention I would like to accomplish some type of generic handling. 
This is where I'm coming from:

```
    class BaseProvider {
    api_url = 'http://localhost:80/api/FILL_OUT_PATH/:id';
    $get($resource){
        var provider = $resource(this.api_url, {}, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
       return provider;
    }
    }
```

and

```
    class User extends BaseProvider{
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.api_url = 'http://localhost:80/api/users/:id';
        }
    }
```

then

```
    module Controllers
    {
        export class BaseController {
            message = "Base controller";
            entity : any;
            entities : any;
            constructor($scope)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
    module Controllers
    {
        export class UserController extends BaseController {
            name = "UserController";
            constructor($scope, User)
            {
                super($scope);

                this.entity = new User();
                this.entities = User.query();
                $scope.vm = this;
            }

        }
    }
```

This is where I'd like to go with UserController (P-Code):

```
module Controllers
        {
            export class UserController<T extends BaseProvider> extends BaseController {
                name = "UserController";
                static $inject = ['$scope', T.typename];        // Inject the types name somehow?
                constructor($scope, entity)     
                {
                    super($scope);

                    this.entity = new T();
                    this.entities = T.query();
                    $scope.user = this;
                }

            }
```

**Is there a facility in typescript to handle this?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a facility in typescript to handle this?

No. All type information is erased from the generated JS so you cannot use generic parameters as variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with generics since there will be no typing related information at the runtime, but as a workaround you can pass the type via constructor and type safety with generics. The following code compiles without error and shows how it could be accomplished.

```
class C1 {
    m() { }
}

class C2 extends C1 { }

class C<T extends C1> {
    constructor(t: { new (): C1 }) {
        var instance = new t();
    }
}

new C(C2);
```